# Question about a function in the argument of a Delta function (distribution)

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

referring to

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160503/what-is-the-wave-propagated-away-from-an-impulsively-excited-spherical-shell

my question concerns the last part of the answer which I quote in the following:

"
$$\frac{R}{2z_o} \int_{-R}^{R}  \delta\left(z_s-\frac{R^2+z_o^2 -c^2t^2}{2z_o}\right) d z_s$$

Now $\int_{-R}^{R}  \delta\left(z_s-\frac{R^2+z_o^2 -c^2t^2}{2z_o}\right) d z_s$ is either one or zero. We know from the way we picked the delta function that the integral is one when $|z_o−R|<ct<z_o+R$ and the integral is zero otherwise. Therefore

$$f(z_o,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{R}{2 z_o}, & |z_o-R|<ct<z_o+R \\
0, & \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
"

( where $f(z_0,t)$ is the result of the integral. )

**My question is:**
*Is there a way to 'analytically' deduce this from the argument of the delta distribution?*

The existing answer's method does not seem totally 'mathematical' otherwise I think the answer may be correct.   Refer to the link for the complete question and answer.  The following figure also may help.

[image: the geometry of the answer]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All of the mass is concentrated on $z_s = \frac{R^2+z_0^2-c^2 t^2}{2z_0}$. Since this quantity is fixed, there is only one such point $z_s$ in the integration range.

Such a value $z_s$ must lie in $[-R,R]$, hence $-2Rz_0 < R^2 +z_0^2 -c^2 t^2 < 2R z_0$ thus you can see that the inequality follows from this.

Comment: R and $z_0$ are parameters and $t$ is a variable so I don't know that the quantity is fixed.

Comment: I mean by varying $t$ there could be a continuum of points $z_0$ that satisfy the equation.

Comment: Yeah totally agree, I'm just considering the integral for fixed $R, t, z_0$ etc